# Should a HOC component with "children" in its props be momoized

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

Specifically, a functional component should accept a "children" props and will render this "children" as a part of its returned object. The purpose is to reduce the extra re-rendering to improve the perfomance, generally in all normal use cases and particularly, supposedly this "children" is a component that contains many levels of nested components.

Main component (HOC):

```
export const HOC = memo((props) => {
    return (
        <div>{props.children}</div>
    )
})
```

And the child might be:

```
export const Child = ((props) => {
     const [a, setA] = useState()

     return (
         <div>
             <B><C/></B>
         </div>
     )
})
```

A use case might be:

```
     <HOC>
          <Child/>
     </HOC>
```

Let's say here in this example the 2 general cases are: setA() is called, which leads to the re-rendering of child, and  gets re-rendered.

With that being said, should I use "memo" in any of these cases, or just in any case generally?

Answer (score 1):

The decision to use `memo` or not to use it must be taken carefully and not blindly. You must realise that whenever you use memo you are essentially asking react to compute the difference between props always and if your cases are such that more often than not the props will change, then using a memo will be an overhead and will degrade the performance since the comparison will almost always cause a re-render.

In your case `HOC` is not actually a higher order component but a normal functional component and again since aren't passing any props to B and C which are passed as children it will be useful for you to use `memo` considering your child component renders quite often